# Android Unit Test launching the emulator but not the test

Tags: android, junit

Im trying to create a unit test extending AndroidTestCase to test a BroadcastReceiver.
In the test I'm:

- instantiating the receiver
- creating an intent with the action and extra parameters needed
- calling the receiver with the intent and getContext()

When I click on debug as Android JUnit Test it starts by launching the emulator (which launches well and usable) and then it hangs at 27% trying to launch the actual test and it never happens.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT, code snippet

```
    public class RemoteControlReceiverTest extends AndroidTestCase {
    public RemoteControlReceiverTest() {
        super();
    }

    private RemoteControlReceiver mReceiver;
    private String accountSettings;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        super.setUp();

        mReceiver = new RemoteControlReceiver();
        accountSettings = "<y>gmail</y><u></u><n>test</n><t>smtp+ssl+://::@:25</t><s>imap+ssl+://:test@:143</s>";
    }

    public void testStartActivity()
    {   
        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.setAction("com.kaseya.email.K9RemoteControl.addAccount");
        addIntent.putExtra("accountSettings", accountSettings);

        mReceiver.onReceive(getContext(), addIntent);
    }
}

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.kaseya.email.test"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

        <instrumentation
            android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
            android:targetPackage="com.kaseya.email" />

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: Post some code snippet (AndroidTestCase.java, AndroidManifest.xml and etc.) may help other people investigate your problem.